# Why my boolean variable doesn't get updated on other classes?

Tags: java, libgdx, boolean

I made a boolean called endGame, and when I click a button it will be set to `false`, and then on another class I made an object for the class where my boolean is. And when something happen the endGame will be set to `true`:

```
if(condition==true){ //the endGame variable will be equal to true only on this class
 classObj.endGame=true;
}

//on the other class where the endGame is Located it is still false.



   //button class
public boolean endGame;
    public void create(){
    endGame=false;

     playButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
               @Override
               public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                   endGame=false;
                   System.out.println(endGame);
                   return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
               }
           });
    }

    //second class
    if(sprite.getY()>=700){
       buttonObj.endGame=true;
       enemyIterator.remove();
       enemies.remove(sprite);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the same instance of classobj? Are you sure you're going through the ode that sets the variable to true?

Comment: Where did you make classObj? is it a global variable? Give us something to work with here!

Comment: Indeed elaborate. One possible case is that endGame is not volatile. If so declare it volatile and check if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and then on another class I made an object for the class where my boolean is

I assume the `endGame` variable is not static. Otherwise you wouldn't need to create an object of the class where the boolean is in order to access it.

This means that if you set `endGame` to true in one object of the relevant class, it wouldn't update the value of `endGame` in different objects of that class.

Comment: So should I set it to Static?

Comment: @StormAsdg That's hard to say without knowing anything about your application. It should either be static, or (if it's not static) all objects that access this boolean should access it using the same object of the relevant class (this way they would all see the same value of the boolean).

Comment: @StormAsdg I recommend you to read through a book on Java. You're really going to struggle trying to make a game in Java without a fundamental understanding of what classes are.

Comment: @Tenfour04 LOL I know what a class is, I wouldn't even be able to write a piece of code on a method if I didn't know what a class is.

Comment: @StormAsdg your question shows that you don't fully understand them, especially the distinction between a class and an instance of a class which truly is fundamental. Just trying to help.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I wasn't trying to be rude, I guess I have to read, I still don't know what an instance is and a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you have several ways to fix that, maybe I'll say this is not the best, but without knowing anything of their code. because if the classes do not inherit from each other, or you can use a singleton pattern ?, I think this example may be worth it for you observer:

```
public class WraControlEndGame {

    private ArrayList<EndGameOBJ> endGameOBJ = new ArrayList<EndGameOBJ>();

    public void addEndGameOBJ(EndGameOBJ actor){
        endGameOBJ.add(actor);
    }

    public void removeEndGameOBJ(EndGameOBJ actor){
        endGameOBJ.remove(actor);
    }

    public void endGameOBJ_ChangeValue(boolean value){

        for(int a = 0; a < endGameOBJ.size(); a++){
            endGameOBJ.get(a).setEndGame(value);
        }

    }
}
```

.

```
public interface EndGameOBJ {
    public void setEndGame(boolean value);
    public boolean getEndGame();
}
```

.

```
public class YourClassThatNeedEndGameVariable implements EndGameOBJ{
..// other code


private boolean endGame = false;

..// other code Construct ect

    @Override
    public void setEndGame(boolean value) {
        endGame = value;
    }

      @Override
    public boolean getEndGame() {
        return endGame;
    }

}
```

.

in your code for example, this a pseudo code, you **implements EndGameOBJ** in your class you need, you view example in **public class YourClassThatNeedEndGameVariable**.

```
someClass buttonObj = new ....;//now this class implements EndGameOBJ
someClass classObj  = new ....;//now this class implements EndGameOBJ

WraControlEndGame wraControlEndGame = new WraControlEndGame();

wraControlEndGame.addEndGameOBJ(buttonObj);
wraControlEndGame.addEndGameOBJ(classObj);

//bla bla bla



if(condition){

    wraControlEndGame.endGameOBJ_ChangeValue(true);
}
```

I hope it will help and apologize for my English.